# Mock api call using moxios

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs, moxios

I am not very familier yet on how to write unit tests via **moxios** and your help would be very much appreciated.

My request is the following:

```
  export const walletRequest = () => {
    return AWAxiosInstance()
        .get(`${AW_BASE_URL}/account/wallet`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response) {
                return formatAccountDetails(response.data);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject('Error requesting data from Account & Wallet API', error)
        })
}
```

So basically here in the above function I'm trying to retrieve some data via an axios instance.

My understanding is that **moxios** is being used to mock the axios instance, but I am not very sure how to write the unit test for the *walletRequest()* function.

**What I've tried:**

```
import  moxios  from 'moxios'
import { walletRequest } from "../balance";
import AWAxiosInstance from '../../../../core/aw-axios-instance'

const responseMock = { balance: 100 };

describe("services/balance2", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        moxios.install(AWAxiosInstance)
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        moxios.uninstall(AWAxiosInstance)
    })

    it("should call the walletRequest and retrieve data", () => {

        moxios.wait(() => {
            const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent()
            request.respondWith({
                status: 200,
                response: {
                    responseMock
                }
            })
        })
        const response = walletRequest().response;
        expect(response).toEqual(responseMock);
    });
});
```

This doesn't work at this moment as the *walletRequest()* response is **undefined**.
What can I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `walletRequest()` is a promise and it doesn't have `response` property. `await` it like you would do in normal circumstances. Even then it's not guaranteed to have it, you didn't show formatAccountDetails. Also there's a mistake, Promise.reject has 1 arg and it discards error object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! This was very useful, I made the changes you suggested and now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install(AWAxiosInstance)
    formatAccountDetails.mockImplementation( () => responseMock)
})

afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall(AWAxiosInstance)
})

it("should return the data", async () => {

    moxios.wait(() => {
        const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent()
        request.respondWith({
            status: 200,
            response: {
                responseMock
            }
        })
    })

    const response = await walletRequest();
    expect(response).toEqual(responseMock);
});

it('should not recieve response when request is rejected', () => {
    const errorResp = {
        status: 400,
        response: { message: 'invalid data', 
                    data: 'invalid data' }
    };

    const response = walletRequest();

    moxios.wait(async() => {
        let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
        request.reject(errorResp);
        response.then((err) => {        
            expect(err).toBe('invalid data');
        });
    });
});
```